# Regex to replace unless in comment

Tags: php, sql, regex, comments

I am trying to write a PHP function that can (given an SQL query with named-printf-style parameters, and an associative array) replace named parameters with a question mark (for SQL prepared statements) and rearrange the array so that the arguments are in the order that they appear in the query.

I have written the following code, which works, however I would like to extend this code so as to ignore named parameters that appear within comments.

```
function sqlprintfn($sql, array $args = array()) {
    $ordered_args = array();
    static $formats = array('b','c','d','e','E','u','f','F','g','G','o','s','x','X');
    $regex = sprintf('/(\?\(([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\)([%s]))/', implode('', $formats));

    // Find the next named argument. Each search starts at the end of the previous replacement
    for ($pos = 0; preg_match($regex, $sql, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $pos);) {
        $arg_pos = $match[0][1];
        $arg_len = strlen($match[0][0]);
        $arg_key = $match[2][0];
        $arg_format = $match[3][0];

        // Programmer did not supply a value for the named argument found in the format string
        if (!array_key_exists($arg_key, $args)) {
            trigger_error(sprintf('%s(): Missing argument \'%s\'', __FUNCTION__, $arg_key), E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        array_push($ordered_args, $args[$arg_key]);

        // Replace the named argument with a question mark
        $sql = substr_replace($sql, $replace = '?', $arg_pos, $arg_len);
        $pos = $arg_pos + strlen($replace); // skip to end of replacement for next iteration
    }

    return array_merge((array) $sql, $ordered_args);
}
```

As an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?(username)s AND type = ?(type)s';
$params = array('type' => 'admin', 'username' => 'bob', email => 'bob@domain.com');
print_r(sqlprintfn($sql, $params));
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND type = ?',
    [1] => 'bob',
    [2] => 'admin'
)
```

And:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE /* email = ?(email)s AND */ username = ?(username)s AND type = ?(type)s';
$params = array('type' => 'admin', 'username' => 'bob', email => 'bob@domain.com');
print_r(sqlprintfn($sql, $params));
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE /* email = ?(email)s AND */ username = ? AND type = ?',
    [1] => 'bob',
    [2] => 'admin'
)
```

Also, note that the $sql variable may be multi-lined.

Comment: It's *reeeeeeally* weird. Use prepared statements instead

Comment: I am using prepared statements, I just want to be able to ensure that the parameters for the prepared statements will always be in the correct order

Comment: um.... so don't use `?` parameters and use named parameters... `user=:username`. you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Is this custom syntax only because of the format suffixes? Are they really needed? -- For your actual problem: just make a temporary SQL string from your input, by stripping `#[/][*].*?[*][/]` out, then process the remaining non-comment-contained variable placeholders.

Comment: @mario, I wanted to leave the comments intact in the output for readability

Comment: @MarcB, can you point me to some document on doing this? I can't find any

Comment: @JoshuaSpence: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: @JoshuaSpence I said *temporary* variable. Find the remaining variables, then apply the loop on the unmodified original $sql string. Yes, more work; which is what you asked for.